# How to combine three variables to send using boost asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to send a set of three variables, a 64 bit integer and two 32 bit integers, using boost asio. I know how to send the data using boost asio but I am struggling to convert the three variables into something I can send using boost asio, any ideas?

The types I'm using for the variables are as follows:

```
boost::uint64_t
boost::uint32_t
boost::uint32_t
```

The purpose of this is to send the data as UDP Tracker Connect Request (Bittorrent Protocol), a description of which can be found here: http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html#udp-tracker-protocol

```
Offset  Size            Name            Value
0       64-bit integer  connection_id   0x41727101980
8       32-bit integer  action          0 // connect
12      32-bit integer  transaction_id
16
```

Comment: Please include relevant code to make possible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Rather than adding more code, it would be more useful to know what you want the data to look like on the wire.  If it is a *problem* for you that boost serialization "adds extra data to the start of the message" (this is probably metadata that it needs to reverse the process later), then you must have some idea of what the message *should* look like, so please tell us that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you're trying to match an existing network protocol that has documented its expected byte offset and endianness for each field.  This is one of the times where you want to use a raw buffer of `uint8_t`.  Your code should look something like this:

```
// This is *not* necessarily the same as sizeof(struct containing 1 uint64_t
// and 2 uint32_t).
#define BT_CONNECT_REQUEST_WIRE_LEN 16

// ...

uint8_t send_buf[BT_CONNECT_REQUEST_WIRE_LEN];

cpu_to_be64(connection_id,        &send_buf[ 0]);
cpu_to_be32(0 /*action=connect*/, &send_buf[ 8]);
cpu_to_be32(transaction_id,       &send_buf[12]);

// transmit 'send_buf' using boost::asio
```

The `cpu_to_be32` function should look like this:

```
void
cpu_to_be32(uint32_t n, uint8_t *dest)
{
    dest[0] = uint8_t((n & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
    dest[1] = uint8_t((n & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    dest[2] = uint8_t((n & 0x0000FF00) >>  8);
    dest[3] = uint8_t((n & 0x000000FF) >>  0);
}
```

The inverse (`be32_to_cpu`) and the analogue (`cpu_to_be64`) are left as exercises.  You might also like to try your hand at writing template functions that deduce the appropriate size from their first argument, but personally I think having an explicit indication of the size in the function name makes this kind of code more self-documenting.

Answer (score 3):

Create a raw memory buffer. Use *endian-aware* copy functions to place the integers in the buffer. Send the buffer.

What endian does the bittorrent protocol use? It's big endian, so any solution here that relies on casting won't work on your typical consumer electronics these days, because these use little-endian format in memory. In creating your buffer to send, you therefore also have to swap the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to convert a structure to `array`/`vector`/`string` which can be sent via `boost::asio`. For example:

```
struct Type
{
    boost::uint64_t v1;
    boost::uint32_t v2;
    boost::uint32_t v3;
}

Type t;

std::string str( reinterpret_cast<char*> (&t), sizeof(t) );
```

I don't know architecture of your application, but it's also possible to create asio::buffer just from memory:

```
boost::asio::buffer( &t, sizeof(t) );
```

In this case you should be careful about lifetime of `t`.

Comment: The `static_cast` won't compile. It's a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: This technique is risky: it assumes that both sides of the communication have the same endianness, and that both sides pad structures exactly the same way.