# Undefined behavior when reading from FIFO

Tags: c++, c, ipc, named-pipes, mkfifo

I am trying to send data from javascript to C via a named pipe/FIFO. Everything seems to be working other than every couple messages there will be an additional iteration of the loop reading `0` bytes rather than the expected `256`. I realize I could add something like `if (bytes_read>0) {...` but this seems like a band aid to a bigger problem.

From my testing it looks like the `open()` call in the `reader` is unblocked when the `writer` opens **AND** closes the file. It looks like sometimes the `reader` is ready (and blocked on open) for the next message before the `writer` closes the file from the previous so it will run through its loop twice per message.

Is this just expected behavior or am I misunderstanding something? Any advice would be greatly appriciated!

**Writer:**

```
uint32_t writer(buf)
{
  int fd;

  // FIFO file path
  char * myfifo = "/tmp/channel";
  
  // Creating the named file(FIFO)
  // mkfifo(<pathname>, <permission>)
  mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
  
  // Open FIFO for write only
  fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);

  uint32_t written = write(fd, buf, sizeof(char)*256);
  close(fd);

  return written;
}
```

**Reader:**

```
int main()
{
    int fd;

    // FIFO file path
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/channel";

    // Creating the named file(FIFO)
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    while (1)
    {
        char buf[256] = "\0";

        // Open FIFO for Read only
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

        // Read from FIFO
        int bytes_read = read(fd, buf, sizeof(char)*256);

        struct access_point *dev = (struct access_point *) &buf;

        printf("Bytes read: %i\n", bytes_read);
        printf("ssid: %s\n", dev->ssid);

        int r = close(fd);
        //sleep(0.01);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After 5 calls to writer the output will look like:

```
# Call 1 (bad)
Bytes read: 256
ssid: kremer
Bytes read: 0
ssid: 

# Call 2
Bytes read: 256
ssid: kremer

# Call 3
Bytes read: 256
ssid: kremer

# Call 4 (bad)
Bytes read: 256
ssid: kremer
Bytes read: 0
ssid: 

# Call 5
Bytes read: 256
ssid: kremer
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when there is no data available to read from the pipe?

Comment: *I realize I could add something like `if (bytes_read>0) {...` but this seems like a band aid to a bigger problem*  Please read the [`read()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/read.html) (bolding added): "The *read()* function shall **attempt** to read *nbyte* bytes..."  Also, `struct access_point *dev = (struct access_point *) &buf;` is a strict-aliasing violation and therefore undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So you are basically saying it is behaving as expected? Also, I am not quite sure what you mean with the aliasing violation. The buffer is created using the same struct from a shared header file on the same machine and is less than 256 bytes. Given this context would it still be considered a strict-aliasing violation? The struct is defined as: 

struct access_point {
    uint8_t packettype;
    uint8_t security;
    uint8_t strength;
    bool known;
    char ssid[33];
    char pass[65];
};

Comment: @akremer You're just plain not allowed to declare an array of `char`, take a pointer to it, cast that pointer to any other type (except `unsigned char *`), and then dereference the cast pointer.  No exceptions.  The correct way to serialize and deserialize a struct to a byte stream is field by field, using functions like the `cpu_to_be32` shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853149/how-to-combine-three-variables-to-send-using-boost-asio/18854567#18854567

Comment: @akremer This doesn't have anything to do with the behavior of `read` on a FIFO, though.  My suggestion for _that_ is that you should try using an `AF_LOCAL` socket instead.

Comment: @zwol I understand that it is technically not allowed but if the data is guaranteed to only run on one machine/cpu would this ever be an issue?

Comment: @akremer yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/5878272

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `read`or 0 bytes indicates the pipe was closed on the other end. So this is absolutely expected behavior.

So you do have to catch that 0 and read again so the kernel waits for the next time the pipe is opened.

Note: `read` can also return `-1` with errno set to `EINTR`. Same deal, just read again.

Answer (score 1):

FIFOs have very nuanced semantics. Here's a sequence of events that can produce such a result. `W` refers top the writing thread. `R` refers to the reading thread.

```
W: opens the fifo, is blocked until the reader opens the FIFO
R: opens the fifo
W: open succeeds
W: write succeeds
R: read succeeds
W: closes the fifo
W: back at the top of its loop
W: it opens the fifo again, it succeeds because the reader hasn't closed it yet
W: writes to the fifo
R: reader finally closes the fifo, after it receives the first message
R: reader closes the fifo, this effectively causes W's 2nd message to get flushed down the drain
R: back at the top of its loop
R: opens the fifo, the writer still has it open
R: enters read
W: closes the fifo
R: reads 0 bytes
```

You have no guarantees, whatsoever, of the relative sequence of multiple events that occurs in both threads. As such, you might get unexpected results.